# How to add pagecontrol for uiscroll view?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hi im new for iphone application development.i wanna use page controller for my uiscroll view.In single view im using two scroll views and two page controls.i setted pagecontrol with following codings but only for two pages its working fine.but i wanna add more than two pages for a scroll view whic consist of static buttons.![enter image description here][1]

```
//
//  newsampleViewController.m
//  newsample
//
//  Created by SmartJobDevelopers on 4/3/12.
//  Copyright 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "newsampleViewController.h"

@implementation newsampleViewController

@synthesize scr_anger;
@synthesize scr_sketch;

@synthesize pageControl;
@synthesize pageControl1;

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [self setupPage];



    //[scr_anger setScrollEnabled:YES];
    //[scr_anger setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1290,15)];

    //[scr_sketch setScrollEnabled:YES];
    //[scr_sketch setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1310,15)];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
        i_curtag=(int)[sender tag];
        //NSLog(@"%d",i_curtag);
        [self fn_btnOperation];
        //[self opt:str_filename];
        //NSLog(@"str_filename:%@",str_filename);
   }

-(void)fn_btnOperation
{
    if (i_curtag==1)
    {
        //str_filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i_curtag];
        //NSLog(@"str_filename:%@",str_filename);
        str_filename=@"1.png";
       // NSLog(@"1.png");
    }
    else if(i_curtag==2)
    {
        str_filename=@"2.png";
        //NSLog(@"2.png");
    }
    else if(i_curtag==3)
    {
        str_filename=@"3.png";
        //NSLog(@"3.png");
    }
    else if(i_curtag==4)
    {
        str_filename=@"4.png";
       // NSLog(@"4.png");
    }
    else if(i_curtag==5)
    {
        str_filename=@"5.png";
        //NSLog(@"5.png");
    }
    else if(i_curtag==6)
    {
        str_filename=@"6.png";
        //NSLog(@"6.png");
    }
    else if(i_curtag==7)
    {
        str_filename=@"7.png";
       // NSLog(@"7.png");
    }
    else if(i_curtag==8)
    {
        str_filename=@"8.png";
        //NSLog(@"8.png");
    }
    else if(i_curtag==9)
    {
        str_filename=@"9.png";
       // NSLog(@"9.png");
    }
    else if(i_curtag==10)
    {
        str_filename=@"10.png";
       // NSLog(@"10.png");
    }

    [self opt:str_filename];
}

-(id)opt:(NSString*)filename
{
    //NSLog(@"filename:%@",filename);
    str_filename=filename;
    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Save Image" otherButtonTitles:@"Mail Image",nil];
    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];
    [popupQuery release];   
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex1
{
    if (buttonIndex1 == 0)
    {
       // NSLog(@"str_filename in actionsheet:%@",str_filename);
        [self savesingleimage];
       // NSLog(@"save");
    } 

    else if (buttonIndex1 == 1)
    {
        //NSLog(@"str_filename in else:%@",str_filename);
        [self fmail];
        //NSLog(@"mail");
    }
}

-(void)fmail
{   
    //NSLog(@"str_filename:%@",str_filename);

        NSMutableString *emailBody = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"<html><body><p>"] retain];

    [emailBody appendString:@"<b><u>EMOTIONAL ICONS</u></b><br><br>"];

    [emailBody appendString:@"</p></body></html>"];

        MFMailComposeViewController *emailDialog = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    UIImage *icon1 = [UIImage imageNamed:str_filename];
    NSData *imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(icon1, 1);
    [emailDialog addAttachmentData:imageData1 mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:str_filename];
        emailDialog.mailComposeDelegate =self;
        [emailDialog setSubject:@"Emotional Icons"];
        [emailDialog setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
        [emailDialog.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        [self presentModalViewController:emailDialog animated:YES];
        [emailDialog release];
        [emailBody release];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Status:" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            alert.message = @"Message Canceled";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            alert.message = @"Message Saved";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            alert.message = @"Message Sent";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            alert.message = @"Message Failed";
            break;
        default:
            alert.message = @"Message Not Sent";
            break;  
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

-(void)savesingleimage{

   // NSLog(@"str_filename in save: %@",str_filename);
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:str_filename];    
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image1, nil, nil, nil);
    UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Saved" 
        message:@"Image Saved into PhotoAlbum" 
        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 170, 50, 50)];
    NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:str_filename]];
    UIImage *bkgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [imageView setImage:bkgImg];
    [bkgImg release];
    [path release];

    [successAlert addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    [successAlert show];
    [successAlert release];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark The Guts
- (void)setupPage
{
    scr_anger.delegate = self;
    scr_sketch.delegate =self;

    //[self.scr_anger setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [scr_anger setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    [scr_sketch setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

    scr_anger.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scr_anger.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scr_anger.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scr_anger.pagingEnabled = YES;

    scr_sketch.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scr_sketch.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scr_sketch.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scr_sketch.pagingEnabled = YES;

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 2;
    self.pageControl1.numberOfPages = 2;


    [scr_anger setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scr_sketch setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [scr_anger setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1290,15)];
    [scr_sketch setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1940,15)];

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate stuff
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView
{
   // NSLog(@"scrollview val=%d",_scrollView.tag);
    i=_scrollView.tag;
   // NSLog(@"i=%d",i);
    if (_scrollView.tag==101) {

    if (pageControlIsChangingPage) {
        return;
    }

    /*
     *  We switch page at 50% across
     */

     //scr_anger.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 0);
    CGFloat pageWidth =scr_anger.frame.size.width;
    //NSLog(@"pagewidth=%f",pageWidth);
    int page = floor((scr_anger.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
   // NSLog(@"page=%d",page);
    pageControl.currentPage = page;
        }
    else if(_scrollView.tag==102)
    {
        if (pageControlIsChangingPage) {
            return;
        }

        /*
         *  We switch page at 50% across
         */

        CGFloat pageWidth =scr_sketch.frame.size.width;

        int page = floor((scr_sketch.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;

        pageControl1.currentPage = page;
        NSLog(@"page=%d",page);
    }
}


- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView 
{
    pageControlIsChangingPage = NO;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PageControl stuff
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender 
{
    /*
     *  Change the scroll view
     */
    //NSLog(@"i=%d",i);
    if (i==101) {


    CGRect frame = scr_anger.frame;


    //pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 390, 320, 15);
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pageControl.currentPage;
      frame.origin.y = 0;

    [scr_anger scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    /*
     *  When the animated scrolling finishings, scrollViewDidEndDecelerating will turn this off
     */
    pageControlIsChangingPage = YES;
    }

    else if(i==102)
    {
        CGRect frame1 = scr_sketch.frame;

        frame1.origin.x = frame1.size.width * pageControl1.currentPage;
        frame1.origin.y = 0;

        [scr_sketch scrollRectToVisible:frame1 animated:YES];

        pageControlIsChangingPage = YES;
    }

}



/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [scr_anger release];
    [scr_sketch release];

    [pageControl release];
    [pageControl1 release];
        // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: since im new to stackoverflow i couldnt add image...

Comment: You have added your image correctly.After added you just deleted the spaces.That made your image unusable.Upload it again and dont delete anything after that. Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/#comment-14154) is a relly good tutorial about UIScrollView&IPageControl combination. But I my self look for a tutorail for more dynamic designs(like main page of ios applications-i increments-decrements automatically)

Comment: hi thanks a lot.i checked with tat tutorial.since im new to developing i couldnt understand it fully.im using 2 scroll views in single view.for each scroll view i have to set page control with multiple page.its working fine for two pages but not for 3rd one.could u please help me?

Comment: @MythiliLakshmanan it may be becases of the count of arrays. Can you share some code or error log?

Comment: hi ilis, i have shared my full coding in above question.could u please chech nd fix my prbl?

Comment: @MythiliLakshmanan i will take a look at it at evening(about 4-5 haurs later) i really have n time now. is it ok?

Comment: hi did u check with my coding?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a information : http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html

Comment: hi thanks a lot.i checked with tat tutorial.since im new to developing i couldnt understand it fully.im using 2 scroll views in single view.for each scroll view i have to set page control with multiple page.its working fine for two pages but not for 3rd one.could u please help me?

Comment: sure can u please share me some further information or code .or else please send me a mail maheswaran.cm@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

In your `setupPage:` method, You have a code to allow number of pages like this.

```
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 2;
self.pageControl1.numberOfPages = 2;
```

If you want to increase a numberOfPages, then increase the numberOfPages in these lines.

Comment: Hi thanks.i tried it but its not working.its adding pages in page control(in dots) but my problem is its not increasing in my scroll view.in scroll view its showing only two pages.

Comment: You have to increase the scrollView ContentSize depend upon number Of pages.